# Online validator for W3C’s HTML5

Tags: web-apps, html, validation, hosted

I’m looking for a hosted Web app that validates HTML5 documents.

The tool **must** be able to check the document for conformance to the [HTML5 W3C Recommendation from 2014-10-28](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/). That means, for example, that it should report an error for a document that uses a `picture` element (as it’s not part of W3C’s HTML5 Rec).

Checking conformance to [W3C’s HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/) and to [WHATWG’s HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) is not required, but would be nice to have *in addition*.

Pasting the document is preferred, but checking via URL or by uploading a file would be okay, too.

Support for extensions (like Microdata, RDFa, …) would be great, but it’s not required.

What I’ve tried:

- **https://validator.w3.org/** redirects to https://validator.w3.org/nu/ for HTML5
- **https://validator.w3.org/nu/** (which is [referenced by the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/introduction.html#how-to-catch-mistakes-when-writing-html:-validators-and-conformance-checkers)) seems to be for W3C’s draft of HTML 5.1
- **https://html5.validator.nu/** (which is referenced by https://validator.whatwg.org/) seems to be for WHATWG’s HTML
- **https://validator.nu/** seems to use the same rules as https://html5.validator.nu/
- **https://www.onlinewebcheck.com/** (which is referenced by https://validator.whatwg.org/) seems to use HTML 5.1 (at least, when validating a document with the `picture` element, their warning speaks of "an experimental HTML 5.1 element")
- **https://checker.html5.org/** seems to be for WHATWG’s HTML

Comment: How do each of the listed services not meet your requirements? What prompted you to post this Question? You must make your criteria clear to provoke good answers. As far as I know https://validator.w3.org/ does the job you asked for.

Comment: @BasilBourque: It’s in the second sentence, with the bolded "must": I need a conformance checker for the HTML5 W3C Recommendation, which, for example, doesn’t define a `picture` element (so the checker must report an error if `picture` is used). -- As also explained in the question (first bullet point), https://validator.w3.org/ redirects to the Nu validator if you want to check HTML5.